# Using f-strings as templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Previously, I've used `str.format()` as a templating method, for example:

```py
template = "Hello, my name is {0} and I'm {1} years old, my favourite colour is {2}"

# Rest of the program...

print(template.format("John", "30", "Red"))
```

I've recently learned of f-strings, and I'm interested to see if there's a way of using it in this manner; defining a template and substituting in the appropriate values when needed, rather than the contents of the braces being immediately evaluated.

Comment: `name, age, color = "John", "30", "Red"` can fit into f-string using `f"Hello, my name is {name} and I'm {age} years old, my favorite colour is {color}"`

Comment: @pissall I want to be able to first define my template string, to have values inserted later; it doesn't seem like this is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't store a f-string for deferred evaluation.

You could wrap it in a function, but that's not really any more readable imo:

```py
def template(*, name, age, colour):
    return f"Hello, my name is {name} and I'm {age} years old, my favourite colour is {colour}"
# ...
print(template(name="John", age="30", colour="Red"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it considered better practice to use f-strings over `str.format()`, or is it more a matter of preference/convenience?

Comment: Matter of preference. When possible to use, I find f-strings easier to read since you don't have to visually scan the expression back and forth to see what the actual value is.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I could increase readability by using `{name}` rather than `{0}`.